# Bash command completion of command parameters

Tags: bash, command-line

In Fedora 21, we can type:

```
apt-get ins
```

hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, and it will complete the word install

We are using an instance of Ubuntu 10.04 on a cloud platform, and tab completion works for files, but does not work for command parameters.

Is there any way to get this to happen on Ubuntu 10.04? We have to stick for compatibility with software running in this virtual machine.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for superuser.com.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Can I migrate myself?

Comment: @Tuknutx: The desktop edition has reached end-of-life, but the server edition (and server packages) is still supported.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```